# Angular 2 with cshtml

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, angular, razor

I'm here just to know if angular2 views work with cshtml files? I was actually implementing users and roles in mvc and thought I would render angular2 html page in my cshtml page but that seems to be impossible for me. What I am doing exactly is:

TestController.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace UserDemo.Controllers
{
    public class TestController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Test
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult GetHtmlPage(string path)
        {
            return new FilePathResult(path, "text/html");
        }
    }
}
```

Index.html of TestController:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Test</h2>

<div>
    @Html.Action("GetHtmlPage", "Test", new { path = "~/index.html" })
</div>
```

Index.html is my angular2 view but it keeps in resulting errors while loading in cshtml!

Comment: We could guess what kinds of errors you are seeing, or you could update your question.

Comment: What did you expect to get?